# Error springboot version 2.3.8.RELEASE Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I recently migrated my springboot to 2.3.8.RELEASE version. Initially it was working fine for couple of week but after adding more API's I get following error not sure it is due to hibernate version conflict or with the java version(1.8.0_25). I tired different ways but still no luck.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2021-03-30 17:55:39,158 ERROR [main] boot.SpringApplication (SpringApplication.java:837) - Application run failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'spotRateController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'spotRateService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'spotRateServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'spotRateDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'spotRateDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'spotRateRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spotRateRepository' defined in com.sg.fo.referential.repository.SpotRateRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on FoLiteApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$154/1987083830.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405) [spring-boot-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.8.RELEASE]
        at com.sg.fo.FoLiteApplication.main(FoLiteApplication.java:32) [classes!/:0.1]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) [genesis.war:0.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107) [genesis.war:0.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) [genesis.war:0.1]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59) [genesis.war:0.1]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'spotRateServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'spotRateDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'spotRateDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'spotRateRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spotRateRepository' defined in com.sg.fo.referential.repository.SpotRateRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on FoLiteApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$154/1987083830.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        ... 29 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'spotRateDaoImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'spotRateRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spotRateRepository' defined in com.sg.fo.referential.repository.SpotRateRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on FoLiteApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$154/1987083830.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$154/1987083830.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        ... 29 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'spotRateRepository' defined in com.sg.fo.referential.repository.SpotRateRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on FoLiteApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$154/1987083830.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$154/1987083830.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.util.JpaMetamodel.lambda$isSingleIdAttribute$4(JpaMetamodel.java:94) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.util.JpaMetamodel$$Lambda$1021/227644740.test(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.Optional.filter(Optional.java:178) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.util.JpaMetamodel.isSingleIdAttribute(JpaMetamodel.java:94) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentPropertyImpl.lambda$new$2(JpaPersistentPropertyImpl.java:110) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentPropertyImpl$$Lambda$1013/1952473604.get(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentPropertyImpl.isIdProperty(JpaPersistentPropertyImpl.java:141) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl.returnPropertyIfBetterIdPropertyCandidateOrNull(JpaPersistentEntityImpl.java:72) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl.returnPropertyIfBetterIdPropertyCandidateOrNull(JpaPersistentEntityImpl.java:39) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.addPersistentProperty(BasicPersistentEntity.java:218) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.createAndRegisterProperty(AbstractMappingContext.java:552) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext$PersistentPropertyCreator.doWith(AbstractMappingContext.java:520) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithFields(ReflectionUtils.java:705) ~[spring-core-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.12.RELEASE]
        at
```

Pom.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you didn't annotated some class properly.
Just check it once.

I will be better if you share source code.

Check if you annotated SpotRateService class with @Service and SpotRateDao with @Repository.

Comment: I have annotated the service and Dao class properly. The issue is because of IncompatibleClassChangeError

Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.util.JpaMetamodel.lambda$isSingleIdAttribute$4(JpaMetamodel.java:94) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.6.RELEASE]

Answer (score 0):

I had resolved this issue by using version of java(1.8.0_92) instead of version(1.8.0_25).

Not sure why and how, but it helped to fix the issue.